# Unable to Logout of Facebook within Unity IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am trying to logout of Facebook within my Unity app using an IPAD Mini. When I try to logout within my app using FB.Logout() it does not log me out of Facebook, so when I call FB.Login() it just automatically logs in with the currently open FB session instead of letting me login with a new FB account. I need this functionality for a kiosk environment. Any help is appreciated.

My problem is the same as this one:
[FB.Logout() not working in Facebook UnitySDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244611/fb-logout-not-working-in-facebook-unitysdk)